# Maven, how to disable by profiling the copying of one resource by the war plugin?

Tags: maven, resources

Inside a maven project with some resources configured like this :

```
<webResources>
    ....
    <resource>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/${temp.dir}</directory>
    </resource>
</webResources>
```

the ${temp.dir} is generated conditionally by a plugin and do not exists always. When it is not there maven of course fail with an NPE, how could I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what your problem (exactly) is, but it seems to me that Maven profiles could help you:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

In your case, probably you need profile activation on property existence, like this:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>temp.dir</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: The profile which generates this folder is active by default. The second profile disable the folder generation but do not disable the copying of this folder by the war plugin. I would like to fix somehow this - when the folder exists copy it, when it do not do not copy it(because when it try to copy it it fails).

Comment: OK, so try my solution. IMHO it could work. You should add additional `maven-war-plugin` config within the profile, that adds this `resource`.

Comment: the maven war plugin has a lot of config, I should copy all the config inside the profile definition for changing 1 line ?

Comment: Just try to add this 1 line or at most `webResource` block. Maven should merge configs. Alternatively, where I'm sure it works, put `maven-war-plugin` configuration within `pluginManagement` section and use the profile to just tune it.

Comment: Of course it's not. `<profile>` tag has same content structure as `<project>` tag itself, so `<build><plugins>...` is valid.